# Как считать всю строку после определенного слова

Tags: строки, c++

Извините за такой нубский вопрос но строки это моя самая слабая сторона) вообшем есть текстовый фаил.Если в нем встречается слово ,например  string то надо скопировать в другую строку всю эту строчку т.е от слова string (не включая его) до конца линии.притом что слово 
string может повторяца несколько раз

Comment: М-М-м. Не понял, а куда все комментарии и ответы подевались?!

Comment: WTF!? @Asen, Вы бы если вопрос закрываете как "повтор", то хотя бы ссылку давали на оригинал!

Котик_хочет_кушать удалил ответ участника Котик_хочет_кушать в вопросе Как считать всю строку после определенного слова
2 часа назад

Борис Бегинин комментировал ответ участника Котик_хочет_кушать в вопросе Как считать всю строку после определенного слова
10 часов назад

Борис Бегинин принял ответ участника Котик_хочет_кушать на вопрос Как считать всю строку после определенного слова

Comment: @gecube Извините, не думал, что вызову такой резонанс. Я удалил старый ответ, потому что он плохой, и можно ответить лучше *(что, собственно, я и намереваюсь сделать).* Видимо, я и впрямь зря утащил за собой все обсуждение в комментариях.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, да я тут уже в панике бегаю. Мало ли кто чей аккаунт поломал. Да и Asen реально отжог с закрытием темы как повтора.

Comment: Действительно, @Котик, странный поступок.

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое решение - это читать все слова, пока не найдется нужное, затем считать строку:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string read_line_after(std::istream& stream, const std::string& what) {
    for (std::string word; stream >> word;) {
        if (word == what) {
            std::string line;
            std::getline(stream, line);
            return line;
        }
    }
    return "";
}


int main() {
    std::stringstream stream(R"(
        x1 y1
        x2 y2 string line2 string text2
        x3 y3 string line3 text3
        )");
    std::cout << "'" << read_line_after(stream, "string") << "'\n";
    // напечатается ' line2 string text2'
}
```